# react native simulator can not connect server on MAC

Tags: ios, react-native, macos

> Could not connect to development server.
>
> Ensure the following:
>
> - Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
> - Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
> - WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server
>
> URL:
> http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
>
> RCTFatal
> __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release
> _dispatch_client_callout
> _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
> __CFRunLoopRun CFRunLoopRunSpecific GSEventRunModal
> -[UIApplication _run] UIApplicationMain main start_sim 0x0

this error show in device simulator
Normally it work ,but today problem appear By without change my react native code

I  npm start at react native root folder. Metro bundler is stuck at 99.4% when  call from device simulator

My react-native. version is  0.61.2

I try solve it by many solution from google , but it not work yet.
please. suggest me

Answer (score 0):

> Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed
> out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device,
> check if you have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.
>
> RCTFatal
> -[RCTWebSocketExecutor setUp] facebook::react::(anonymous namespace)::RCTObjcExecutor::RCTObjcExecutor(id,
> void (NSError*) block_pointer,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1facebook::react::ExecutorDelegate)
> facebook::react::(anonymous
> namespace)::RCTObjcExecutor::RCTObjcExecutor(id,
> void (NSError*) block_pointer,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1facebook::react::ExecutorDelegate)
> facebook::react::RCTObjcExecutorFactory::createJSExecutor(std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ExecutorDelegate,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread) (anonymous
> namespace)::GetDescAdapter::createJSExecutor(std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ExecutorDelegate,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread)
> facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::NativeToJsBridge(facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory*,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::InstanceCallback)
> facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::NativeToJsBridge(facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory*,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::InstanceCallback)
> std::__1::__unique_iffacebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::__unique_single
> std::__1::make_unique<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge,
> facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory*,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry&,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread&,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::InstanceCallback&>(facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory*&&,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry&,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread&,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::InstanceCallback&)
> facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0::operator()()
> decltype(std::__1::forward<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0&>(fp)())
> std::__1::__invoke<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0&>(facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0&) void
> std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void,
> true>::__call<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0&>(facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0&)
> std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0,
> std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0>, void
> ()>::operator()()
> std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0,
> std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)::$_0>, void
> ()>::operator()() std::__1::__function::__value_func<void
> ()>::operator()() const std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()()
> const facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()>
> const&)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()>
> const&)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2::operator()() const
> decltype(std::__1::forward<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2&>(fp)())
> std::__1::__invoke<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2&>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2&) void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void,
> true>::__call<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2&>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2&)
> std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2,
> std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2>, void ()>::operator()()
> std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2,
> std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_2>, void ()>::operator()()
> std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const
> std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueueSync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)
> facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback,
> std::__1::default_deletefacebook::react::InstanceCallback >,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::JSExecutorFactory,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::MessageQueueThread,
> std::__1::shared_ptrfacebook::react::ModuleRegistry)
> -[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridgeLocked:]
> -[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]
> __21-[RCTCxxBridge start]_block_invoke.166 decltype(std::__1::forward<void () block_pointer __strong&>(fp)())
> std::__1::__invoke<void () block_pointer __strong&>(&&,
> decltype(std::__1::forward<void () block_pointer
> __strong&>(fp)())&&...) void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<void ()
> block_pointer __strong&>(void () block_pointer __strong&)
> std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<void () block_pointer __strong,
> std::__1::allocatorstd::__1::allocator, void ()>::operator()()
> std::__1::__function::__func<void () block_pointer __strong,
> std::__1::allocatorstd::__1::allocator, void ()>::operator()()
> std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const
> std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const
> facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
> -[RCTCxxBridge _tryAndHandleError:]
> __NSThreadPerformPerform
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
> __CFRunLoopDoSource0
> __CFRunLoopDoSources0
> __CFRunLoopRun CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop]
> **NSThread__start**
> _pthread_start thread_start

sometime above error show at  simulator

Answer (score 0):

i can solve this.
reason from has below code in somefile in my project

```
import { isGetAccessor } from 'typescript';
```

when i rid its my project come back to work again